# IdentityServer4: "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.LocateRepository" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: identityserver4

I have cloned the IdentityServer4 project from Git. I have cleaned the solution and build it. I am getting "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.LocateRepository" task failed unexpectedly build error.

I resolved all package incompatibility issues. I am getting error on build like this:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.LocateRepository" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.GitEnvironment.CreateFromProcessEnvironment() in /*/src/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git/GitDataReader/GitEnvironment.cs:line 56
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.RepositoryTask.GetOrCreateRepositoryInstance() in /*/src/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git/RepositoryTask.cs:line 110
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.RepositoryTask.ExecuteImpl() in /*/src/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git/RepositoryTask.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.RepositoryTask.Execute() in /*/src/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git/RepositoryTask.cs:line 32
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() IdentityServer4 C:\Users\INPRPAT12.nuget\packages\microsoft.build.tasks.git\1.0.0-beta2-19324-01\build\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets   10

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Use sample projects instead of repo clone.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius, May i know why repo clone will not work?!